# Web service call works in script task but times out in the script component

Tags: c#, ssis

Hey I've been bashing my head against the wall in this problem and havent been able to solve it yet.

Basically I need to use a web service which it works for me in a script task but the same service times out in a script component. I realized that i need to use a data flow script component for this since I need to use the script as the source of data, which the script component is specialized.

My code in the script Task.

```
public void Main()
    {
        // the below detail can be pulled from database and send to the service.  
        string infoProvider = Dts.Variables["$Package::infoProvider"].Value.ToString();
        string query = Dts.Variables["$Package::query"].Value.ToString();



        Z_OPERACIONES.GetQueryViewData queryViewData = new Z_OPERACIONES.GetQueryViewData();
        Z_OPERACIONES.GetQueryViewDataResponse queryViewDataResponse = new Z_OPERACIONES.GetQueryViewDataResponse();
        Z_OPERACIONES.Z_OPERACIONES operaciones = new Z_OPERACIONES.Z_OPERACIONES();
        Z_OPERACIONES.RrwsSxAxisData axisData = new Z_OPERACIONES.RrwsSxAxisData();
        Z_OPERACIONES.RrwsSxTuple item = new Z_OPERACIONES.RrwsSxTuple();

        queryViewData.Infoprovider = infoProvider;
        queryViewData.Query = query;
        operaciones.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Dts.Variables["$Package::credUsername"].Value.ToString(), Dts.Variables["$Package::credPassword"].GetSensitiveValue().ToString());


        queryViewDataResponse = operaciones.GetQueryViewData(queryViewData);
    }
```

My code in the script component

```
    public override void PreExecute()
{
    base.PreExecute();

    // the below detail can be pulled from database and send to the service.  

    string infoProvider = this.Variables.infoProvider;
    string query = this.Variables.query;


    SC_086d647fa758458096b528e6d977aa21.Z_OPERACIONES.GetQueryViewData queryViewData = new SC_086d647fa758458096b528e6d977aa21.Z_OPERACIONES.GetQueryViewData();
    SC_086d647fa758458096b528e6d977aa21.Z_OPERACIONES.GetQueryViewDataResponse queryViewDataResponse = new SC_086d647fa758458096b528e6d977aa21.Z_OPERACIONES.GetQueryViewDataResponse();
    SC_086d647fa758458096b528e6d977aa21.Z_OPERACIONES.Z_OPERACIONES operaciones = new SC_086d647fa758458096b528e6d977aa21.Z_OPERACIONES.Z_OPERACIONES();
    SC_086d647fa758458096b528e6d977aa21.Z_OPERACIONES.RrwsSxAxisData axisData = new SC_086d647fa758458096b528e6d977aa21.Z_OPERACIONES.RrwsSxAxisData();
    SC_086d647fa758458096b528e6d977aa21.Z_OPERACIONES.RrwsSxTuple item = new SC_086d647fa758458096b528e6d977aa21.Z_OPERACIONES.RrwsSxTuple();





    queryViewData.Infoprovider = infoProvider;
    queryViewData.Query = query;
    operaciones.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(this.Variables.credUsername, this.Variables.credPassword);


    queryViewDataResponse = operaciones.GetQueryViewData(queryViewData);
}
```

Comment: I think you should set the request time out somewhere. But you didn't provide the request method code since you are using a anonymous class called `Z_OPERACIONES`. If you can provide the class methods code it can be more clear.

Comment: sure the method i'm trying to use is called GetQueryViewData()

Here's the code for that method

    public GetQueryViewDataResponse GetQueryViewData([System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("GetQueryViewData", Namespace="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style")] GetQueryViewData GetQueryViewData1) {
            object[] results = this.Invoke("GetQueryViewData", new object[] {
                        GetQueryViewData1});
            return ((GetQueryViewDataResponse)(results[0]));
        }

Comment: in `operaciones` class check if there is a timeout property

Comment: there's not a timeout property under the operaciones class